# Using regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to manipulate the string as following: 
`myStr = 'str1/str2/str3a // str3b'`. 
I would like to get the last value seperated by delimiter `'%s/%s'`, in this case `'str3a // str3b'`. 
I tried using string split, but it splits based on '//' and returns str3b. Is there a way i can address this problem using regex?

Thanks

Comment: How come the value separated by %s/%s becomes str3a // str3b ? you have a double / not a %s/%s.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the regular expression `(?:^|[^/])\/(?!\/)((?:[^/]|\/{2,})*)$`:

```js
var strings = [
  'str1/str2/str3a // str3b',
  'str1/str2/str3',
  'str1/str2'
]

strings.forEach(function(string) {

  var match = /(?:^|[^/])\/(?!\/)((?:[^/]|\/{2,})*)$/.exec(string)[1]

  console.log(string, '=>', match)

})
```

Comment: but this does not work when string input is just 'str1/str2'. I would still want to return str2

Comment: Just updated the answer. Should work for your other uses now.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to get the string as following. myStr = 'str1/str2/str3', which case i would return the last string with delimiter '/' (result = str3). Or myStr = 'st1/str2/str3 // str4' (result would be 'str3 // str4' - last string followed demilited by '/'). The above solution does not check for this cases. strsplit is not smart enough to detect this.

Comment: I think I understand now. I updated my answer and confirmed that it works for all three strings you mentioned above.